# Nested if statement in a for loop syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

While working with a dictionary loop on, I want to include an if statement to check if a developer has more than one favourite language and modify the statement to plural.  Can some one help with the syntax please?

```
favorite_languages = {
'jen': ['python','ruby']
'sarah': ['c'],
'edward': ['ruby','C++'],
'phil': ['python'],
}

    for name, language in favorite_languages.items():
        print(name.title() + "'s favorite language is " +
        language.title() + ".")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: watch for indentation in Python.

Comment: favorite_languages = {
    'jen':['python','ruby'],
    'sarah': ['c','HTML'],
    'edward': ['ruby'],
    'phil': ['python','excel'],
    }         
for name,language in favorite_languages.items():
    for language1 in language:    
        if len(language1)>1): 
            print('\n'+name+"'s favourite languages are:")
        else:
            print('\n'+name+"'s favourite language is:")
    print(language1.title())

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` statement:

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],  # forgot comma here
    'sarah': ['c'],
    'edward': ['ruby', 'C++'],
    'phil': ['python'],
}

for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():  # lost indentation here
    if len(languages) > 1:
        print('{}\'s favorite languages are {}.'.format(name.title(), ", ".join(languages)))
    else:
        print('{}\'s favorite language is {}.'.format(
            name.title(), 
            languages[0].title(),
        ))
```

Comment: I think OP wants a `print()` more like this: `print("{}'s favorite languages are {}.".format(name.title(), ", ".join(language)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `str.format`.

```
favorite_languages = {'jen': ['python','ruby'],
                      'sarah': ['c'],
                      'edward': ['ruby','C++'],
                      'phil': ['python']}

for name, language in favorite_languages.items():
    print("{0}'s favorite language{1} {2}".format(name.title(),
          's are' if len(language)>1 else ' is', ' and '.join(language)))
```

Result:

```
Jen's favorite languages are python and ruby
Sarah's favorite language is c
Edward's favorite languages are ruby and C++
Phil's favorite language is python
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you wanted:

```
        print('{}\'s favorite ' +('language is' if len(language.title()==1) else'languages are')+ '{}.'.format(
```

I wrote this a bit quickly and I don’t know how dictionaries work, so if this is incorrect, please let me know.